# Batch: Output file names with relative paths to files and additional signs

Tags: file, batch-file, path, relative-path, names

I have a folder structure like this:

- c:/foo/bar1/a002345.vi
- c:/foo/bar1/somefilename.vi
- c:/foo/bar2/b005632.vi
- ...
- c:/foo/bar26/z002345.vi

Now I want to execute a batch file in the folder c:/foo/ which writes the following output to a .txt file:

```
@@/bar1/a002345.vi
@@/bar2/b005632.vi
@@/bar26/z002345.vi
```

(Without somefile.vi) What's the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: You can use `find` or `findstr` with the /v switch to filter out a filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please specify how you will differentiate "somefile.vi", does it not contain any numbers, or do you know its individual name?

If it is the latter, I believe this should work if run from the C:\foo folder

```
for /r %%a in (*) do (if %%~na NEQ somefile echo %%~pa%%~na%%~xa >> output.txt)
```

Note instead of "@@\bar..." you will get "\foo\bar..."
If there are multiple files you want to exclude simple nest more if commands:

```
for /r %%a in (*) do (if %%~na NEQ somefile1 if %%~na NEQ somefile2 if %%~na NEQ somefile3 echo %%~pa%%~na%%~xa >> output.txt)
```

And so on....
I've tried this on my computer and it worked fine.

Yours, Mona

Comment: Thanks, this also works for me and saves me a lot of time! But sometimes I have more files like 'somefile.vi'. They could be multiple files, but they never contain numbers in their file names. Do you also have a solution for this? Like a wildcard for numbers only?

Comment: As far as my knowledge in batch scripting extends, there is no wildcard for numbers only, and since the only way to process each word for numbers is if they're on a seperate line, the only thing i could suggest is creating a mini script, that displays the name of the file, and asks for input such as "y" or "n", and based on the input it decides if it should echo the path+name+extension into output.txt